# pass data from popup gridview to parent page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, aspxgridview

the explanation given here http://wiki.asp.net/404.aspx?aspxerrorpath=/themes/fan/pages/page.aspx/282/passing-value-from-popup-window-to-parent-form39s-textbox/

is exactly what I want , but Its not giving the output and parent page despite doing exactly as explained ,

can anyone please send sample website with northwind data base ? no need of mdf file ,just a tested demo I will attach Northwind .

The task s simple , In pop up window there is a grid with some databound column and one with button , my task is when buton is clicked it must return text from respective grd row to the parent page'control (any)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is not working to you because on the sample is hard code the button id, and this logically because on the popup window did not know how the button have been render.

```
getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_TextBox2")
```

So ether correct this id to make it as its appear to your page, ether make the control id on TextBox2 static so is not change, and get it by name.

Comment: I did these options , but no gain
to perform this task I did many searches and used many aspects but dont know whats the issue